# Expected value for a sorted collection

Tags: probability

We have a collection of n numbers (duplicates can appear). We try to sort the collection by randomly shuffling the collection. What is the expected number of times we have to shuffle the collection to get it sorted? We assume that every permutation has an equal chance.

Comment: You want the expected value of a geometric random variable with parameter $k/n!$, where $k$ is the number of permutations of the elements which result in a sorted list. This is $n!/k$. How many such permutations are there (as a function of the duplicate structure)?

Comment: I am by no means an authority, but I suggest you to read some article on markov analysis and mixing times. The motivated question of mixing times is "how many times do we have to shuffle a deck of cards before it is 'shuffled'".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all the numbers are different, the probability is $\frac{1}{n!}$ of getting the right permutation in one try. Suppose $k$ of them are the same number, the probability is $\frac{k!}{n!}$ of getting the right permutation in one try. Suppose we have classes of sizes $k_1,\ldots,k_m$ such that each number in a class is equal. Then we have probability $\frac{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_m!}{n!}$ of getting the right permutation in one try. Since this is a geometric proces, we get expected value $\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_m!}$.